# How to pick out the element in a list of lists which satisfies a particular condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sorting

I have got a list:

```
lis:={
{{1, 2, 3, 4}},
{{1, 2, 3}, {4}},
{{1, 2, 4}, {3}},
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
{{1, 2}, {3}, {4}},
{{1, 3, 4}, {2}},
{{1, 3}, {2}, {4}},
{{1, 4}, {2, 3}},
{{1}, {2, 3, 4}},
{{1}, {2, 3}, {4}},
{{1, 4}, {2}, {3}},
{{1}, {2, 4}, {3}},
{{1}, {2}, {3, 4}},
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}
};
```

and I would like to pick out those lists which satisfy the following condition:

```
list == Mod[list+2,4,1]
```

but, they should be "equal" as a set of lists, not in a "element to element" way. For example, `{{1,2},{3,4}}` is a list satisfied the condition, since `Mod[{{1,2},{3,4}}+2,4,1]` is `{{3, 4}, {1, 2}}`, which is not equal to `{{1,2},{3,4}}` since the "position" is not  right, but we should regard it as equal in the sense of set, since they are both the set of `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`.

An example which not satisfied our condition is that `{{1,2,3},4}`, since `Mod[{{1, 2, 3}, 4} + 2, 4, 1]` is `{{3, 4, 1}, 2}`, as a set they are not equal, one is the union of `{1,2,3}` and `{4}`, but the results is the union of `{1,3,4}` and `{2}`.

Can I use a pattern to sort out the one satisfied my condition in the list? I would like to make it work with any list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my reading of your question is correct, this does the job:

```
sets = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
        {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}},
        {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}},
        {{1, 4}, {2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}},
        {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}};

Cases[sets, list_List /; Equal @@ Map[Sort, {list, Mod[list + 2, 4, 1]}, 2]]
   {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}},
    {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}}
```

Comment: yes, it seems you were right, thanks! but could you please explain the code for me? why it works?

Comment: The condition I used within `Cases[]` can be written in an equivalent, longer, but maybe more transparent form: `Sort[Map[Sort, list]] == Sort[Map[Sort, Mod[list + 2, 4, 1]]]`. I trust that this form might be more understandable to you. The key is in the third argument of `Map[]`; see the docs for details.

Comment: you means that the argument 2 of map means to sort the two list in the list {list, mod...}(whose element are numbers), not to sort the whole list (whose elements are lists)?

Comment: If you're doubting how something like `Map[]` works here, it is instructive to replace the `Sort[]` with a "generic" function. Try `Remove[f]; With[{l = {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}}, Map[f, {l, Mod[l + 2, 4, 1]}, 2]]`.

Comment: ok, good demo. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A more mathematically intuitive formulation would be to use `Intersection`, as then the logic is self-explanatory. You can also create a custom container to make the sets orderless so that `{1,2,3}`, `{3,1,2}` and `{2,3,1}` are all treated the same (alternately, you can use `Sort`). For example:

```
equivalentQ[func_] := Block[{f},
    SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
    With[{set = # /. List -> f}, 
        Intersection[set, func@# /. List -> f] === set
    ]
] &;
```

Sets that equal those transformed by `func` should yield `True`. With this, you can write your condition as

```
 cond = equivalentQ[Mod[# + 2, 4, 1] &]
```

(and easily extend it to other transformation functions).

1. **`Select`:**

   ```
   Select[list, cond]
   (* {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}}, 
       {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}} *)
   ```
2. **`Cases`:**

   ```
   Cases[list, x_List /; cond[x]]
   ```
3. **`Pick`:**

   ```
   Pick[list, cond /@ list]
   ```
4. **`Reap` & `Sow`:**

   ```
   Last@Reap@Scan[If[cond[#], Sow[#]] &, list]
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I failed to spell out a working solution for your problem the first time.  Here is what I intended:

```
sortall = # /. List :> Composition[Sort, List]&;

Select[lis, sortall @ #  === sortall @ Mod[# + 2, 4, 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}},
>  {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}}
> ```

J.M.'s method is cleaner, and in this case without a downside that I can see.  (The `sortall` function is useful if you want to sorts Lists and *only* Lists at *any* level in an expression.)  I still prefer `Select` here:

```
Select[lis, Equal @@ Map[Sort, {#, Mod[# + 2, 4, 1]}, 2] &]
```

Comment: they are both not work for the lis={{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}.

Comment: @vanabel please explain in detail how that set passes your test.

Comment: (Mod[# + 6/2, 6, 1] /. List :> Composition[Sort, List]) & /@ lis
will output {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}}, which is not equal to {{1,5,6},{2,3,4}} as a "list".

Comment: Both versions miss the lists with a mix of singletons and longer lists, like `{{1, 3}, {2}, {4}}`. To fix the first one: `Select[lis, Sort[Sort /@ #] === Sort[Sort /@ Mod[# + 2, 4, 1]] &]`

Answer (score 3):

Along the same lines as  @R.M.'s approach:

```
eqvlntQ = Union[Union /@ #] == Union[Union /@ Mod[# + 2, 4, 1]] &;
```

which can be used with `Pick`, `Select`, `Cases` and `Reap/Sow` as in @R.M's answer.

```
Row[{{#, eqvlntQ[#]} & /@ sets // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &, 
 Pick[sets, eqvlntQ /@ sets] // Column[#, Frame -> All] &}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: yes, you were right: since Union has the function of sort as mentioned the doc


`Union[list_1,list_2],...]
gives a sorted list of all the distinct elements that appear in any of the list_i. `